# Script to convert .csv file to .xlsx

Tags: excel, csv, vbscript

I want to convert .csv files to .xls. The files are created by another application without .csv suffix (`ex.1` for example). I have background in C++ and C#.
There are a lot of VBScript examples but I don't know how to start, where to write the script, how to run it. I would appreciate a detailed answer.

Comment: Google vba for beginners, you will find everything described - how to start Visual Basic in excel and run codes. Like this one http://www.excel-vba.com/excel-vba-solutions-beginners.htm

Comment: Give *any* CSV file a ".csv" file extension, and Excel will open it. Then do a "Save As" and change to .XLSX extension...  If you need to repeat this for many files, record some macros of each step (i.e., opening a file as one step, save as another step).  We can help you put them together, but SO is not a code-writing service and you are expected to put forth more effort than "show me where to start" (Google...)

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple with Pyexcel https://pyexcel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ for Python.

```
import pyexcel.cookbook import merge_all_to_a_book
import pyexcel.ext.xlsx
import glob

merge_all_to_a_book(glob.glob("test.csv"), "excelformat.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0):

If all of the files you wish to convert are in the same folder, you can use this code.  As an option, if you don't need to save the original files, delete the oFSO.CopyFile line and un-comment out the oFSO.MoveFile line.  Additional checking might be needed if other files are in the same folder.

```
Option Explicit                                                         'Require all vars to be declared
Dim oXLApp, sCSVFiles, oFSO, oFiles                                     'Vars required
Dim oFile, sCSVName, sDestinName, oWorkBook                             'Vars required
Set oXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")                          'Create excel object
oXLApp.Visible = True                                                   'Make excel visible
oXLApp.DisplayAlerts = False                                            'Tell excel to not alert when saving files
sCSVFiles = "E:\Sample\"                                                'Folder where files to convert are
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")                   'Create a File System Object
Set oFiles = oFSO.GetFolder(sCSVFiles).Files                            'Get list of files in the folder
For Each oFile In oFiles                                                'Look at each file in the folder
    sCSVName = oFile.Path & ".csv"                                      'Create the csv file name
    sDestinName = oFile.Path & ".xlsx"                                  'Create the excel file name
    If oFSO.FileExists(sCSVName) Then oFSO.DeleteFile(sCSVName)         'If csv name exists delete it
    If oFSO.FileExists(sDestinName) Then oFSO.DeleteFile(sDestinName)   'If excel name exists delete it
    oFSO.CopyFile oFile.Path, sCSVName                                  'Copy the file into CSV file ext
    'oFSO.MoveFile oFile.Path, sCSVName                                 'Rename the existing file
    Set oWorkBook = oXLApp.Workbooks.Open(sCSVName)                     'Open the CSV file
    oWorkbook.SaveAs sDestinName                                        'Save it as the default excel file type
    oXLApp.Workbooks.Close                                              'Close the workbook
Next                                                                    'Process next file in the folder
oXLApp.DisplayAlerts = True                                             'Excel bug Fix: turn back on alerts
oXLApp.Quit                                                             'Exit excel
Set oFiles = Nothing                                                    'Destroy the oFile object
Set oFSO = Nothing                                                      'Destroy the FSO object
Set oXLApp = Nothing                                                    'Destroy the excel object
```